# Find records with specific month

Tags: excel, vba

i need to find all records of a column with a specific month with excel VBA.
I have a column with dates (dd.mm.yyyy) and need for example
all rows where mm.yyyy is for example "01.2020", so i get all
rows where the year is 2022 and the month is January.

```
.Find(what:="01.2022", LookIn:=xlValues)
```

doesn't work at all.

Comment: *"doesn't work at all"* - can you be more specific? Do you see errors or does the code not find the cells? The code you've provided in your question would find cells containing `01.2022` so there must be something else causing the issue. Perhaps sharing more code would help.

Comment: Try using wilcards. Something like `What:="*.01.2022"` should work

Comment: Both of your solutions doesn't work and it doesnt find anything, my solution doesnt find anything either.. when i try .Find(what:=CDate("01.01.2022"), LookIn:=xlValues) it finds the specific row with the date, but i need all days in a month

Comment: `CDate("01.01.2022")` is read as `26/10/4670` Are you sure your dates in cells are read as dates and not as strings? Can you add a data example and expected output?

Comment: Could you include your full code - `Find` will never find _all_ records without `FindNext`.  Not sure how to find within a range of dates/numbers.  Maybe filter and look at visible cells would be better?

Answer (score 1):

This will filter a list of dates in column A to those in March.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A102411")
    
    With rng
    
        'The Parent of rng is the Worksheet.
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    
        'Apply filter.
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                    Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(DateSerial(2022, 3, 1)), _
                    Operator:=xlAnd, _
                    Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(DateSerial(2022, 3, 31))
                    
        'rng is resized to exclude the header, and only look at visible cells.
        Dim rFiltered As Range
        Set rFiltered = rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
          
        'Can look at each cell in turn and build a reference
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim rCell As Range
        Dim rReturn As Range
        For Each rCell In rFiltered
            If rReturn Is Nothing Then
                Set rReturn = rCell
            Else
                Set rReturn = Union(rReturn, rCell)
            End If
        Next rCell
        
        'Can look at all addresses returned by filter - rFiltered.Address.
        MsgBox rFiltered.Cells.Count & " cells found." & vbCr & vbCr & _
               "Returned addresses: " & vbCr & _
               rFiltered.Address
        
        'Remove the applied filter if it filtered anything.
        'Pretty sure this line could be placed directly after "Set rFiltered" without any problems.
        If .Parent.FilterMode Then .Parent.ShowAllData
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```